# Code completion for JavaScript library in Atom editor

Tags: javascript, dojo, atom-editor

How can I activate code completion in [Atom editor](https://atom.io/) for a JavaScript library like [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, Atom does not do that by default (no editor does that), and there are no packages to do that either.

As far as I know, there aren't much code completion plugins for IDE's. There's the [Needs more Dojo](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7264) plugin for the IntelliJ family (WebStorm, ...) but that's the only one I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably if someone had made a Dojo package for Atom it would be here: https://atom.io/packages

I couldn't find one, though.